# Animation is working on two of the three sliders but not on the first one

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I have used Fadeup animation of animate CSS inside the Owl Carousel slider for captions and descriptions. Animation is working on two of the three sliders but not on the first one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please add your code with detail where you facing issue.